# how to know if batch job is running

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, scheduling, scheduler

I have an oracle batch job which runs every 15 min. For some reasons, there might be possibility that the business logic being executed in batch job, might take more than 15 minutes. Is there any possible way i can check if the batch job is still in process ?

i.e.

batch job runs (process 1) takes 20 min
after 15 min, the same batch job runs (process 2) .. I want to check if the batch jobn with this name is already in running or not.

there is a `procedure` which copies large chunk of data from one record to other. this procedure is being executed every 15 minutes by using `dbms_scheduler` i.e. `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULER`, creating program using `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM` and using these 2 in `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB`

Comment: It would be helpful to provide more details about what this "batch job" does.  Is this something scheduled in the database via `DBMS_JOB` or `DBMS_SCHEDULER`?  Is there something in the `V$SESSION` table that identifies a session as belonging to the batch job?  Is there some table it updates that could be queried?  Can you modify the batch job to do either of these things?

Comment: there is a `procedure` which copies large chunk of data from one record to other. this procedure is being executed every 15 minutes by a `dbms_job` which scheduled using `dbms_scheduler`.

Comment: `dbms_job` and `dbms_scheduler` are two different scheduling packages in the Oracle database (`dbms_scheduler` is the newer and much enhanced version).  It is very unlikely that you are using both packages to run a job-- it would make vastly more sense to use one or the other.  Are you sure that you're actually using both?  If so, how exactly is that implemented?

Comment: I edited my original question and posted how it is implemented. I am using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` only.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from all_scheduler_running_jobs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `select * from [dba_scheduler_jobs][1];` and look at the state column for your job.

Comment: Question: Doesn't DBSM_SCHEDULER make it sure that the second instance of the same job doesn't run?